# How do I create a random letter generator that loops

Tags: python, random, ascii, letter

*So I´m very new to python and just trying to create a letter generator.
The output should be like this: `aaa aab abb bbb aac acc ccc ...`
No uppercase letters, no digits, no double outputs, just a 3 letter long random letter loop.
Hope Someone can help me, Greetings*

Edit: I´ve now created a working code that generates a 3 letter long word but now I have the problem that they are getting generated several times. I know the loop function looks weird but I mean it works.

```
import string, random
    count = 0
    while count < 1:
    
    randomLetter1 = random.choice(
        string.ascii_lowercase
    )
    
    randomLetter2 = random.choice(
        string.ascii_lowercase
    )
    
    randomLetter3 = random.choice(
        string.ascii_lowercase
    )
    
    print(randomLetter1 + randomLetter2 + randomLetter3)
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? We won't write code for you but we are more than happy to answer specific questions or problems you run into. To start look into [random](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html) to get started

Comment: Hmm, that doesn't sound like random at all. Actually sounds like a job for itertools.product() and string.ascii_lowercase to me! :D

Comment: @joshmeranda I´ve now edited my question.

Comment: "but I mean it works" It doesn't. It is a syntax error and every obvious fix of that would turn it into an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

The example you posted (aaa, aab, abb, etc.) does not seem like a random letter generator to me, but here's the method I would use to randomly generate 3-letter strings:

```
# choice allows us to randomly choose an element from a list
from random import choice

letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']

randomString = ''

for i in range(3):
    randomString += choice(letters)
```

If you want to create a list of these strings, then just loop the last 3 lines several times and add the results to a list like this:

```
charList = []

for i in range(x):
    randomString = ''

    for i in range(3):
        randomString += choice(letters)
    
    charList.append(randomString)
```

where x is the number of strings you want to generate. There are definitely many other ways to do something like this, but as you mentioned you're a beginner this would probably be the easiest method.

EDIT: As for the new problem you posted, you've simply forgotten to increment the count variable, which leads to the while loop running infinitely. In general, should you see a loop continue infinitely you should immediate check to see if the exit condition ever becomes true.

Comment: Are you aware of random.choice**s**?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi yes, but you'd still have to iterate over the list it returns to get a full string, so I prefer to use choice in this situation

Comment: There is no need for explicit iteration: `''.join(random.choices(letters, k=3))`

Comment: @MisterMiyagi ahh that had slipped my mind for a minute, you're right. How did i manage to forget about .join?!